# Displaying mysql values inside combobox php

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I am trying to display a series of numbers(table field name = "tag number" from a MySQL database table called milk in a combo-box. It is inside of an input table. However i am not sure what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
 <form name="test_form" id="test_form" method="post" action="InputBase.php">

  <tbody>
    <?php

        //set up mysql connection
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        //select database
        mysql_select_db("dairy herd system") or die(mysql_error());
        // Retrieve all the data from the "tblstudent" table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cow") or die(mysql_error());
        // store the record of the "tblstudent" table into $row


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // Print out the contents of the entry 
            echo '<tr>'

        //$results = mysql_query("SELECT tag_number FROM milk") or die(mysql_error());
        $query = ("SELECT tag_number FROM milk") or die(mysql_error());
        $results = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
        {                             
        echo '<td>  
        <option value='.$row['tag_number'].'></option>
        </td>';

        }



            echo '<td><input type="text" size = "3" name= "input1"></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" size = "3" name= "input2"></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" size = "3" name= "input3"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" size = "3" name= "input4"></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>';'</tr>';


        }
        ?>      

  </tbody>
```

The error i am getting is as follows:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in G:\xampp\htdocs\bootstraptable\input1.php on line 66

This is the line that queries the database to select tag_number from milk

[image: how it currently looks]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74428/discussion-on-question-by-conor94-displaying-mysql-values-inside-combobox-php).

Answer (score 0):

You have a little star in your code. This will cause your script to fail.

With this, you NEED to properly escape any values displayed in HTML to the user with the PHP [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function. This is to prevent [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks, which opens your users to a wide range of security risk and attack.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{                             
    echo '<td>  
    <option value='.htmlentities($row['tag_number']).'></option>
    </td>';
}* <---- REMOVE THIS STAR
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i just added the star to highlight the part of my code that i am trying to add the tag_number to the combobox. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

you will get some idea from this it is just a select box which will show all your entries (tag_numbers) from database

> ```
> $hostname_localhost ="localhost";
> $database_localhost ="dairy herd system";
> $username_localhost ="root";
> $password_localhost ="";
> $localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
> or
> trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
>
> mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
>
>
>
> $query ="SELECT tag_number FROM milk";
>  $result = mysql_query($query); 
>
>
> ?>
>       <select  name="tag_number" >
>       <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?> 
>
>       <option value="<?php echo $line['tag_number'];?>"> <?php echo $line['tag_number'];?>
>
>   </option>   <?php } ?> </select>
> ```